# Difference in the output of NIntegrate versus Integrate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I have an expression which when integrated, should be a cumulative distribution function (CDF). I have integrated the expression using both **NIntegrate[]** and **Integrate[]**. When the CDF returned by NIntegrate[] and Integrate[] are compared, the solutions are different and my question is why? Below is the computation:

```
nIntegratePlot = Plot[
  NIntegrate[
   (E^(-(1/288) (-30 + A3)^2)
     Erfc[1.5371886547533642` (32 - Nf - 4.4` Log[50 - A3])])/(
   24 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]),
   {A3, 0, 50},
   Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0},
   MinRecursion -> 10,
   MaxRecursion -> 20,
   AccuracyGoal -> 15,
   PrecisionGoal -> 15
   ],
  {Nf, 5, 40}
  ]
```

[image: result of NIntegrate]

Now for Integrate[],

```
integrateValue = Integrate[
  (E^(-(1/288) (-30 + A3)^2)
    Erfc[1.5371886547533642` (32 - Nf - 4.4` Log[50 - A3])])/(
  24 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]),
  {A3, 0, 50}
  ]
```

0.473 - 0.246895 Erf[22.7306 - 1.53719 Nf] -
0.226105 Erf[240.8 - 1.53719 Nf]

Plotting the the result of Integrate[], I get:

```
integratePlot = Plot[integrateValue, {Nf, 5, 40}]
```

[image: result of Integrate[]]

Comparing both results, I get:

```
Show[{nIntegratePlot, integratePlot}]
```

[image: comparison of NIntegrate and Integrate]

Can someone help me figure out what is going on? Why are the results different?

Additional, If I try to do

```
Plot[
 
 Integrate[
  (E^(-(1/288) (-30 + A3)^2)
    Erfc[1.5371886547533642` (32 - Nf - 4.4` Log[50 - A3])])/(
  24 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]),
  {A3, 0, 50}
  
  ],
 {Nf, 5, 40}
 ]
```

It runs forever. What is going on here too?

** I am using version v12.2**

Comment: Your definition of `integrateValue` has a dangling comma, though I doubt that's the issue

Comment: @barrycarter, Thank you. Your eyesight is better than mine lol. Fixed it.

Comment: I also find it vaguely annoying that `integrateValue` should be a function of `Nf` and `A3` and that your plot has an `Nf` range in one case and an `A3` range in another case (which might be the issue)

Comment: @barrycarter, I don't think I agree with you. The first Plot[], has range for Nf. The second Plot[] also has a range for Nf. The function being integrated is a function of Nf and A3. I integrate with respect to A3 and then plot along the Nf {Nf,5,40}.  Maybe I don't understand you clearly?

Comment: You're right, sorry, I didn't catch that. I still think you should turn both integrations into functions and plot as functions-- it's possible that `NIntegrate` is spitting out warnings that are somehow getting absorbed. You can also then plot the difference between the two functions. Of course, the "obvious" answer is that numerical integration is never 100% accurate, but this might help you find why it's more inaccurate for higher values.

Comment: @barrycarter, Maybe defining Integrate[] as a function and passing that into Plot[] will correct the result. However, that has not answered the question as to why Mathematica is giving an answer that appears wrong.  As you see at the end of my question, I tried to do that and It takes forever.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137599/discussion-between-barrycarter-and-tom6639).